# Is there a short hand for setting readonly property in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I often repeatedly do this in vb.net

```
Private _nerfed As Boolean
Public ReadOnly Property nerfed As Boolean
    Get
        Return _nerfed
    End Get
End Property
```

I wonder if there is a short hand one?

I know that

```
Private _nerfed As Boolean
Public Property nerfed As Boolean
    Get
        Return _nerfed
    End Get
    Set (nerfed)
        _nerfed =nerfed
    End Get
End Property
```

can be shortened with simply

```
Public Property nerfed As Boolean
```

So what about the readonly variant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB now has read-only auto-implemented properties: Just add the `ReadOnly` keyword to the Property declaration. Here's an example:

```vb
Public ReadOnly Property Id As String
```

Comment: the other answer is also good. I just select this one for mentioning auto implemented

Answer (score 4):

ReadOnly shorthand properties are available since VB 2010:

```
Public ReadOnly Property nerfed As Boolean
```

And in VB 2015, you can initialize them:

```
Public ReadOnly Property nerfed As Boolean = True
```

Comment: and the private variable will automatically be _nerfed?

Comment: Well, VB will use a hidden private field - the naming will only be of consequence to the compiler.

Comment: As @J.Chang says, the private variable will prefixed with an underscore. You can use it anywhere in your class, so it is really like the C# syntax with {get; private set;}. This is not only of consequence to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add to the other answers..

We can read more here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers, in case of an auto implemented property that is also implementing an interface, the value goes **before** the interface implementation! Had me searching for a while.

```vb
Public ReadOnly Property Nerfed As Boolean = True Implements INerf.Nerfed
```