# How do I make a readonly computed property in VB.NET without specifying the full Get / End Get syntax?

Tags: vb.net

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050263/is-there-a-short-hand-for-setting-readonly-property-in-vb-net) but it only showed how to make constant readonly properties. I want a readonly computed property, that is reevaluated every time it's executed. So I can do something like this:

```
Public Property A As Double

Public Property B As Double

Public ReadOnly Property C As Double = Math.Sqrt(A * B) ' this will just save off the initial values of A and B and not recompute when they change, right?
```

In C# you can make a readonly property reevaluate each type by using the lambda operator instead of an equals sign:

```
private Random rng = new Random();

public int NotRandomNumber { get; } = rng.Next(); // caches the value

public int ActualRandomNumber { get; } => rng.Next(); // recomputes the value
```

But VB doesn't have a lambda operator that I'm aware of. So is there any way to do this in VB? Or do I have to write it out in full, with `Get` / `End Get` / `Return`?

Comment: The first is an initializer, the second an Expression body (which should be written, when applied to one of the accessors, as `public int ActualRandomNumber1 { get => rng.Next(); }` or `public int ActualRandomNumber => rng.Next();` when applied to a read-only property). VB.Net has just the first. The latter needs an explicit Getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need the full `Get` --> `End Get` with the `ReadOnly` modifier:

```
Public ReadOnly Property C As Double
    Get
        Return Math.Sqrt(A * B)
    End Get
End Property
```

VB.Net is VERBOSE...BY DESIGN.

If you want less verbosity, switch to C#?